# Why is this potion texture missing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Today I was working on a "Smoke Bomb" in Minecraft. It's basically just a lingering potion that has blindness on it. Here's the command I came up with:

```
/give @p lingering_potion 1 8198 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:15,Amplifier:1,Duration:600}],display:{Name:"Smoke Bomb"}}
```

But when I put it into a command block, it gives me this:
[image]

Which is the missing texture block. Why is that command giving me a lingering potion with no texture?

UPDATE: The potion part of the command works well. It's just that the texture is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the data value to 0; it's no longer used for defining a potion's effect:

```
/give @p lingering_potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:15,Amplifier:1,Duration:600}],display:{Name:"Smoke Bomb"}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, when were the data values changed?